# breaks in ggplot not displayed

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple question regarding `breaks` in ggplot. They are not displayed correctly, and I was wondering if someone could hint me at what am I doing wrong.

Here is an example

```
df = data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F,
                ub_ch = c(
                "hand_rh",
                "hand_rh",
                "hand_rh",
                "hand_rh",
                "hand_rh",
                "hand_rh",
                "hand_lf",
                "hand_lf",
                "hand_lf",
                "hand_lf","hand_bh","hand_bh", "shoulder_rh", "shoulder_rh","shoulder_rh","torso_bw")
                )
```

Here the code

```
#ordering bars depending on the number of counts
theTable <- transform(df,ub_ch  = ordered(ub_ch, levels = names( sort(-table(ub_ch))))) 
theTable

#graph
g1<-ggplot(theTable,aes(x=ub_ch,fill = ub_ch))+ scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1))+
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)),position="dodge")+theme_bw()
g2<-g1+theme(panel.background =element_blank(),panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  scale_color_grey(start=0, end=.6) + 
  labs(x="Body articulator") +
  theme(legend.position="none",axis.title.y = element_blank())
g2
```

This is the output

[image]

I want to have breaks on the y-axis from 0-40% every 5%

I added the part of `breaks=seq(0,40, by=5)` to `scale_y_continuous` right after `labels` but it's not working as I wish.

This is what I get

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to have more number of breaks as

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1), n.breaks=8)
```

Then you will get

[image: output]

Comment: Great! It works. I'm attaching a second question: I have a 2nd graph which I'm combining with this graph using ```ggarrange``` but the y-axis scale goes to 15% and I would like the 2nd graph to go up to 40% as the first one. When I add to ```scale_y_continuous()``` the line ```limits= c(0,40)```, labels on the y-axis change to 4000%, 3500%, etc. and bars shrink. I can't figure out how to handle this one. Any advices?

Comment: Try `limits=c(0,0.4)`.  If it does not work, perhaps you should post a separate question with the code you have tried.